# Normals not baking properly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, normals, baking

Im trying to bake normal maps of my character however it doesn't work at all, it just looks as if low poly mesh is baking onto itself, and I can't find a solution to that :/[image]

Comment: hello maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Increase the ray distance a tiny bit and make sure the normals are correct.